# SWT Tree with columns: Remove alternating background coloring for rows on Linux/Mac

Tags: java, linux, macos, tree, swt

I'm coloring some of the columns of a tree with columns (which looks like a Table). On Windows systems it looks good but on Linux/Mac it doesn't because they use alternating background coloring (white, blue, white, blue,...).
I would like to remove the alternating background coloring for the tree. Any ideas if it's possible? I tried to forbid `tree.setLinesVisible(true)` on these systems, but it also won't draw vertical lines, which I need.

Answer (score 0):

I think you can do this using owner draw. Use [this snippet](http://dev.eclipse.org/viewcvs/viewvc.cgi/org.eclipse.swt.snippets/src/org/eclipse/swt/snippets/Snippet229.java?view=co) as starting point, and exchange the `EraseItem` event handler with this:

```
public void handleEvent( Event event ) {
   event.detail &= ~SWT.HOT;
   GC gc = event.gc;
   Rectangle area = table.getClientArea();
   /*
    * If you wish to paint the selection beyond the end of
    * last column, you must change the clipping region.
    */
   int columnCount = table.getColumnCount();
   if ( event.index == columnCount - 1 || columnCount == 0 ) {
      int width = area.x + area.width - event.x;
      if ( width > 0 ) {
         Region region = new Region();
         gc.getClipping(region);
         region.add(event.x, event.y, width, event.height);
         gc.setClipping(region);
         region.dispose();
      }
   }
   gc.setAdvanced(true);
   if ( gc.getAdvanced() ) gc.setAlpha(127);
   Rectangle rect = event.getBounds();
   Color background = gc.getBackground();
   gc.setBackground(display.getSystemColor(SWT.COLOR_RED));
   gc.fillRectangle(0, rect.y, 500, rect.height);
   // restore colors for subsequent drawing
   gc.setBackground(background);
}
```

Should work on GTK (which is the linux window manager SWT uses) and with `Trees`, haven't tried it though.

Since owner draw is expensive I strongly suggest to add such a event handler for GTK:

```
if(SWT.getPlatform().equals("gtk")){ ... }
```

But the whole point of SWT is having native drawing. This improves the user acceptance of your software, because users feel "at home". Maybe you can design a way, where you don't have to take away the alternating background for GTK users.

Comment: This is accurate - but note that there are pitfalls with owner drawing on Mac OS Carbon (never tried on Cocoa) particularly when you start scrolling the table it will lose paint events.  I would +1 on keeping the (expected) native behavior.